# how to not load objects on smaller screen

Tags: css, responsive-design

I want to make my blog responsive so it would looked good on devices with smaller screen. My friend told me about this css function called "@media screen" which worked great for me. I could use *display:none;* to hide anything I want on smaller screen.

but then I realized that *display:none;* only hide the objects but still download the data. meaning visitors using mobile device (with smaller screen) must download data as much as those who are using PCs. Poor those mobile visitors who must download a few hundreds KBs worth of data for a banner they didn't see...

So here's my question:

**"Is there a way to make certain objects (DIVs) to not get loaded on smaller screen?"**

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

You said **"responsive"**. Meaning of responsive is that your site **must be** displayed on all screen sizes on all devices. So it must download all resources and show/hide them accordingly.

Still if you want light-weight site for mobile devices, i will suggest that you should go with mobile-specific site

Answer (score 1):

CSS and HTML works on browser, having said that when HTML or CSS do anything they are always on browser and are probably already loaded. the best of not downloading that DIV is do not add it in your HTML. If you are using Server side script language such as PHP or ASP.NET make sure to put them in condition that if on Mobile device do not "Echo" or render them. another way is you use Javascript and ajax, and call element on ondemand, but again that is lot of server side programming.

Comment: nothing is easy, but if you follow strict MVC, MVVM, or such model then you get real benefits on speed of site and maintaining them.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on browser implementation but if object (image for example) has a parent with "display:none;" most browsers are not downloading it.

However HTML/CSS for this object is of course loaded/parsed etc.and there is no way around it.

This is one of the reasons responsive design is overrated IMHO. Desktop/Mobile version is way more better to provide light version of your website.

Comment: I see... so my dream design is just a pipe dream after all huh...
thank you for answering...

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, give the elements (images, divs etc) a class name so you can target them, then use media queries in your CSS.

eg
**HTML**

```
<p> some text here <img src="#" class="desktop-only"> </p>
```

**CSS**

```
@media (max-width: 979px) {  

.desktop-only{
display:none !important;
}

}
```

You can use any combination media queries you like manipulate the layout and what's displayed. More details [here](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)

FYI, while this removes elements from the page, they are still downloaded by almost all browsers, so if mobile bandwidth is a critical concern to you, check out other options like [Adaptive Images](http://adaptive-images.com) to automatically resize images.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the reply... and yes, I'm concerned about the bandwidth for mobile device users...
I'll try out Adaptive Images and report back after checking thing out...